# Minimize distance between points using equality constraints with unknown variable(s)

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations

I'm looking for an approach to minimize the distance in $\|\cdot\|_2$ between a pair of unknown points $\mathbf{P}_1, \mathbf{P}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a preferred set of points $\mathbf{R}_1, \mathbf{R}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

There is a set of *equality* constraints, each one involving $\mathbf{P}_1$ and/or $\mathbf{P}_2$, which together form a linear system of vector equations.

In addition, these equality constraints contain unknown scalar variables (at least one in total, likely more).

Probably the simplest case is a square non-singular system of equations (i.e. the equality constraints) and a single unknown scalar variable. In that case, the problem amounts to optimizing the value of that scalar variable, in the sense that it minimises $\sum \|\mathbf{R}_i - \mathbf{P}_i\|_2$.

Consider for example the following equality constraints:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{P_1}\\
\mathbf{P_2}
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
e\mathbf{Q_1} + \lambda(\mathbf{Q_2} - \mathbf{Q_1})\\
f\mathbf{Q_2} + \lambda(\mathbf{Q_3} - \mathbf{Q_2})
\end{array}\right),$$

with

- $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ and $f$ known values in $\mathbb{R}$,
- $\mathbf{P_i}$, $i \in \{1,2\}$ unknown elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$,
- $\mathbf{Q_j}$, $j \in \{1,2,3\}$ known elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$,
- $\lambda$ an unknown value in $\mathbb{R}$.

Other cases are *underdetermined* systems of equations and *overdetermined* ones, both of which can occur within my context.

Different aspects of the problem seem to point into different directions (e.g. least squares, normal equations for solving under-/over-determined systems, Lagrange multipliers, ...). As I'm not sure how to proceed from here, references, hints or (partial) solutions would be most welcome.

---

**[Edit]** Updated formulation of the question (removed an aspect that was previously there and has been solved below).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

So we have

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{P_1}\\
\mathbf{P_2}
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
e\mathbf{Q_1} + \lambda(\mathbf{Q_2} - \mathbf{Q_1})\\
f\mathbf{Q_2} + \lambda(\mathbf{Q_3} - \mathbf{Q_2})
\end{array}\right),$$

The main step is to choose a vectorization for the unknowns, for example $\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{P_1}\\
\mathbf{P_2}\\\lambda
\end{array}\right)$

Now try and rewrite your expression to one involving the vectorized unknowns with matrix multiplication and addition.

---

**additional hint**
scalar multiplication $s{\bf A}$ is "syntactic sugar" for $(s{\bf I}){\bf A}$, in other words there is a hidden identity matrix involved.

If $3$ dimensional vectors we can write $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right] \cdot s=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}s&0&0\\0&s&0\\0&0&s\end{array}\right]$$
but in general we want a *Kronecker product* : ${\bf I_N}\otimes s$.

It means inserting copies of $s$ into each element of $\bf I_N$ and multiplying with the scalar there.

---

I can solve it more completely later if you want me to, but it is a good exercise to try do the following procedure oneself.

Comment: Well, symbolically I could rewrite this as 

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & (\mathbf{Q_1} - \mathbf{Q_2})\\
c & d & (\mathbf{Q_2} - \mathbf{Q_3})
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{P_1}\\
\mathbf{P_2}\\
\lambda
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
e\mathbf{Q_1}\\
f\mathbf{Q_2}
\end{array}\right),$$

though I'm not sure how useful this is as the matrix now contains both scalars and vectors (and re-writing the vectors as $3$ scalars each does not seem to make much sense, unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Comment was too long. Wanted to add the following — I'm curious about your approach (though additional hints are also welcome).

Comment: @Ailurus scalar multiplication on matrices/vectors involves a "hidden"/implicit identity matrix. That is often how multiplication by scalar is defined.

Comment: Ah, so I replace $a$ and other scalars by $aI$ in the matrix, turning it into a $6 \times 7$ matrix? That should work :)

Comment: However, using the approach based on normal equations now also requires an initial `guess' for $\lambda$, which influences the eventual solution (it finds the solution closest — in the sense of the 2-norm — to the initial guess). Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: It seems linear in all aspects. I don't see why an initial guess would be needed. It is not like the right hand side is $0$ or anything.

Comment: Right, but the question is how to get $\mathbf{P_i}$ closest to the reference points $\mathbf{R_i}$ by optimizing $\lambda$ (or in some cases, multiple scalar variables). Which approach would you then recommend for this?

Comment: Ah wait I see now. Then you can add a term $\|\sum_j s_{ji} R_j-P_i\|_2, \|\sum_j s_{ji} -1\|_2$ to the minimization and the $s_{ji}$ to the vectorization. Probably you will need to reweight to force $s_{ji}$ to be 0 or 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74142/discussion-between-ailurus-and-mathreadler).